# Using @params with non-mandatory parameters

Tags: powershell

As part of a PS module I'm working on, I want to include a function to export that will update any of the following potential AD group properties:

ManagedBy
extensionAttribute1
extensionAttribute2
extensionAttribute3
extensionAttribute4

I have validation the way I want it for each non-mandatory parameter in my code below, but my question is:

What is the most effective method to pass the parameters' values to a Set-ADUser command? I've included a few possible permutations in some if/elseif's in the code as examples, but since `-ManagedBy` is an included parameter in Set-ADUser, and all the rest can be set by `-Replace @{extensionAttribute1=$Ext1}`,`-Replace @{extensionAttribute2=$Ext2;extensionAttribute3=$Ext3}`, etc. - how can I avoid have more than a dozen possible combinations with a long if/else set?

Would using a hashtable or a dictionary containing what I want to pass in the `-Replace` parameter's value make sense here?

```
Function Update-GroupOwnershipAttributes()
{
<#
.Synopsis
   Allows updating of ManagedBy & extensionAttributes 1-4
   for an Active Directory group
.EXAMPLE
   Update-GroupOwnershipAttributes -Identity someGroupName -ManagedBy someManager -Ext1 -
.EXAMPLE

.INPUTS

.OUTPUTS

.NOTES

.COMPONENT

.ROLE

.FUNCTIONALITY

#>
    [cmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,
                    Position=0,
                    ValueFromPipeline=$True,
                    ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
        [ValidateNotNull()]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [ValidateScript(
            {
                if($(Test-Group $_) -eq $True)
                {
                    $True
                }
                else
                {
                    throw "Group $_ not found"
                }
            }
        )]
        [String]$Identity,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
        [ValidateNotNull()]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [ValidateScript({
            if($(Test-User $_) -eq $True)
            {
                $True
            }
            else
            {
                throw "User $_ not found"
                $False
            }
        })]
        [String]$ManagedBy,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
        [ValidateSet("SomeValueICareAbout")]
        [String]$Ext1,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
        [ValidateSet("True","False")]
        [String]$Ext2,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,
                    Position=3)]
        [ValidateScript(
        {
            if($(Test-User $_) -eq $True)
            {
                $True
            }
            else
            {
                throw "User $_ not found"
                $False
            }
        })]
        [String]$Ext3,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,
                    Position=4)]
        [ValidateScript(
        {
            if($(Test-User $_) -eq $True)
            {
                $True
            }
            else
            {
                throw "User $_ not found"
                $False
            }
        })]
        [String]$Ext4
    )

    BEGIN
    {}
    PROCESS
    {
        # Set arguments so we don't have to have
        # dozens of if/elseif statements
        $params = 
        else
        {

        }
        # All params
        if($ManagedBy -ne $null -and $Ext1 -and $Ext2 -and $Ext3 -and $Ext4)
        {
            try
            {
                #Set-ADGroup -Identity $Identity -ManagedBy $ManagedBy -Replace @{extensionAttribute1=$Ext1;extensionAttribute2=$Ext2;extensionAttribute3=$Ext3;extensionAttribute4=$Ext4}
            }
            catch [Exception]
            {

            }
        }
        # All except Ext1
        elseif($ManagedBy -ne $null -and $Ext2 -and $Ext3 -and $Ext4)
        {
            try
            {
                #Set-ADGroup -Identity $Identity -ManagedBy $ManagedBy -Replace @{extensionAttribute2=$Ext2;extensionAttribute3=$Ext3;extensionAttribute4=$Ext4}
            }
            catch [Exception]
            {

            }
        }
        # All except Ext2
        elseif($ManagedBy -ne $null -and $Ext1 -and $Ext3 -and $Ext4)
        {
            try
            {
                #Set-ADGroup -Identity $Identity -ManagedBy $ManagedBy -Replace @{extensionAttribute1=$Ext1;extensionAttribute3=$Ext3;extensionAttribute4=$Ext4}        
            }
            catch [Exception]
            {

            }
        }
        # All except Ext3
        elseif($ManagedBy -ne $null -and $Ext1 -and $Ext2 -and $Ext4)
        {
            try
            {
                #Set-ADGroup -Identity $Identity -ManagedBy $ManagedBy -Replace @{extensionAttribute1=$Ext1;extensionAttribute2=$Ext2;extensionAttribute4=$Ext4}                
            }
            catch [Exception]
            {

            }
        }
        # All except Ext4
        elseif($ManagedBy -ne $null -and $Ext1 -and $Ext2 -and $Ext3)
        {
            try
            {
                #Set-ADGroup -Identity $Identity -ManagedBy $ManagedBy -Replace @{extensionAttribute1=$Ext1;extensionAttribute2=$Ext2;extensionAttribute4=$Ext3}   
            }
            catch [Exception]
            {

            }
        }
        # All except ManagedBy
        elseif($ManagedBy -eq $null -and $Ext1 -and $Ext2 -and $Ext3 -and $Ext4)
        {
            try
            {
                #Set-ADGroup -Identity $Identity -Replace @{extensionAttribute1=$Ext1;extensionAttribute2=$Ext2;extensionAttribute4=$Ext3}
            }
            catch [Exception]
            {

            }
        }
    }
    END
    {}
}
```

Note: Test-User and Test-Group are functions within my module. If that code is needed, I can post those as well.
I really appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Use `@PSBoundParameters` if your goal is to write a wrapper for these cmdlets.

Comment: Thanks @TheIncorrigible1

Comment: In trying to implement `$PSBoundParameters` in the `PROCESS{}` block of my script, checking `($PSBoundParameters).ContainsKey('ManagedBy')` keeps returning false and `$PSBoundParameters` is empty if I specify my command like:

`Update-GroupOwnershipAttributes -ManagedBy "someExistingUser" -Ext4 "someOtherUser"`

What am I doing wrong? When stepping through in the ISE, trying to look at `@PSBoundParameters` does return results but I'm not sure how to evaluate it.

@TheIncorrigible1 - any pointers?

Comment: `$PSBoundParameters` only populates with the key/value of parameters that are passed to the cmdlet.  It doesn't not pick up default parameter values.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the pro tip!

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I'm still kind of stuck as to how to dynamically approach this. Since the number of -ExtensionAttribute parameters can vary, would it be possible to loop through `$PSBoundParameters` and use `.ContainsKey("ExtensionAttribute1")`, etc., then employ those parameters in the `-Replace` part of my Set-ADUser command?